# Clementine, path to playlists' information

Tags: paths, clementine

Where does Clementine store my playlists and their information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that this information is stored in an sqlite database found here:

```
~/.config/Clementine/clementine.db
```

**References:**

- [Clementine: Frequently asked questions](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions)